# Bug when using dayCellDidMount to customize a day on fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-dom, fullcalendar-6

When I updated my react-dom to v18, this bug popped up.
I made a logic to change the first day of the month to, for example, '01 oct.'.
But with the new version of the react-dom, it kinds of 'mixes' both pattern and changed date.

```
const customDayLabel = (date: Date, view: CalendarView): void => {
  if (view === CalendarView.Month) {
    const currentDate = new Date(date).setDate(DAY_ONE)
    const dates = [addMonths(currentDate, ONE_MONTH), currentDate]

    for (const targetDate of dates) {
      const dataDate = format(targetDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      const element = document.querySelector(
        `.fc-daygrid-day[data-date="${dataDate}"] a`
      )

      if (element) {
        const dateLabel = format(targetDate, 'dd MMM.')
        element.innerHTML = dateLabel
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
const Calendar = ({
  setCalendarRef,
  view,
  date,
  ...otherProps
}: CalendarProps) => {
  const headerView = view || otherProps.initialView || CalendarView.Month
  const dayRender = useCallback(() => {
    customDayLabel(date, headerView)
  }, [date, headerView])

  return (
    <FullCalendar
      ref={setCalendarRef}
      editable
      droppable
      navLinks
      allDayText=''
      locale='pt-BR' // for 0-23 hour format
      forceEventDuration
      moreLinkText='mais'
      headerToolbar={false}
      fixedWeekCount={false}
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      slotLabelFormat={slotLabelFormat}
      dayPopoverFormat={dayPopoverFormat}
      dayHeaderContent={customHeader}
      dayCellDidMount={dayRender}
      initialDate={date}
      {...otherProps}
    />
  )
}
```

What can I do to fix it?

[image: Example Image]

I've tried to replace the `dayCellDidMount` for the `dayCellContent`, but it only renders the label I've changed.